# Old to new 301 redirect parameters for better Google migration?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo, migration

I have changed my domain name and redirecting every request to new domain with index.php like:

```
<?php
// Permanent redirection
$url = "http://newdomain.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".$url);
exit();
?>
```

also with .htaccess like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also made domain changing from Google Webmaster Tools. Should I add something or do sth more to this for better Google migration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're only redirecting requests to files/directories that don't exist. Static files (CSS, JS, images) won't be redirected. The following snippet will avoid PHP entirely and redirect ALL requests to your new domain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

To continue serving static files from the old domain, use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Aside from redirects, make sure you update all links and file references on the new domain. You'll want to keep the redirects online for at least a few weeks to give them a chance to settle in. I also recommend getting in touch with anyone that may be linking to your site and ask that they update their link to reflect the domain change. [Google's Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) can help with this and identifying bad links.

Comment: No problem! I added a bit more info to better answer your question. Don't forget to tick the green checkmark if this is the answer you were looking for :)

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Don't worry, I won't forget. Just waiting for other ideas :)